# Can I apply for a post-doc in global studies in North America?

Tags: postdocs

I am doing my doctorate in global studies in Germany, and would like to apply for a post-doc position in North America, especially in Canada. The topic I work on has considerable policy relevance, and I see that some North American professors are working in those areas. I am a non-EU citizen. Is there any chance that I will be accepted?

Answer (score 4):

I can only speak for the US.

Yes!  US universities routinely hire postdocs from all over the world.  A few positions may be reserved for US citizens, due to funding requirements, but those will be indicated in the postings.

As one way to check, go to the web site of a department that interests you, find the web pages of some of the postdocs, and read their CVs.

Comment: How is PostDoc admission procedure in North America? Should one apply to the research group or to the university centralized system? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly routine to hire foreign postdocs in the US. The main issue to worry about is the work visa - the faculty mentor might not have much of an idea so if you did get an offer you'd have to discuss it with them and probably some admin folks at the university.

Comment: How is PostDoc admission procedure in North America? Should one apply to the research group or to the university centralized system? Thanks

Comment: The mentor hires, but the ad might be posted by the university. But in my (limited) experience all communication is directly with the hiring PI. The ad posting would probably have instructions on how to apply.

Comment: Actually, the postdoc hiring (**not "admission"**) process varies significantly depending on the field and the university.  Most postdocs are hired directly by PIs.  But others are hired by departments (for example, most math postdocs) or sub-departments (for example, the Simons postdoc in theoretical CS).  Still others are "hired" by funding agencies (for example, NSF mathematical sciences postdocs, or the former Computing Innovations postdocs).