# In the social sciences, is it easier to get a post doc than a PhD?

Tags: phd, application, postdocs

I am completing a PhD in Global Studies in Germany, and would like to apply for a post doc in North America, especially Canada. However, I am not sure if there is funding for post docs in the social sciences. For international students is it easier to apply for a PhD than for a post doc?
 I have a publication in an edited book from a prestigious publisher, another in English in a peer reviewed journal published from Germany.

Comment: I think the question could use some clarification.  It's not exactly the same as your previous question (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/), but there's some overlap in that both are about moving from a German Ph.D. program in global studies to a postdoc in Canada.  Another issue is that the title here ("is it easier to get a post doc than a PhD?") doesn't seem to me to have much to do with the body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a PhD, the chances of being admitted into a second PhD program are quite low, I would imagine. Furthermore, I would not recommend such a strategy: the possibility of being labeled as a "perpetual student" could have negative ramifications on one's career.

That said, there is funding for post-doctoral associates in addition to graduate students, even in the social sciences; in particular, there are a [number of fellowships](http://gsasgrants.fas.harvard.edu/) that are designed specifically for postdoctoral candidates in the humanities and social sciences. Of course, there is relatively more funding for PhD's than for postdoctoral associates.

Comment: Why are the chances low, why wouldn't they hire a PhD? Let's assume the field is not exactly the same.